# How to find limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!^{n^{e^{2}}}}{2^{n!}}$

Tags: limits

How to find: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!^{n^{e^{2}}}}{2^{n!}}?$$
I've tried with [Stirling’s approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), but it's not easy too. Maybe there is a simple way?

Comment: Generally when comparing fancy fast-growing expressions like $n!^{n^{e^2}}$ and $2^{n!}$, it will often be the case that one of them grows _hysterically much faster_ than the other -- in which case you can get away with making quite broad and sweeping estimations. For example $n!<n^n$ and $e^2<3^2<9$, so $n!^{n^{e^2}}<n^{n^{10}}$. That gets you to something where you can fairly easily take the logarithm on both sides of the fraction bar ...

Comment: It would be possible for others to comment on your method for alternative steps if you post the solution you came up with.

Comment: @DatBoi OP didn’t say they had found a solution. They said that they had tried StirlinG’s approximation, but it turned out “not so easy.” It *could* mean that OP had found a messy solution with this approach, but it also could mean that OP had abandoned this approach because they couldn’t make it work.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok! I misinterpreted it

Comment: See this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ltlsjbq0gl), your limit, not rigorously, is $\infty$.

Comment: Graphs can be deceiving.

Comment: @Troposphere That is why I said “not rigorously”, but in this case it seems that the graph is correct. To asker, try $\log_b$(limit)

Comment: @TymaGaidash: Your graph shows only $x$ up to $10$ -- so with a similar graph you could conclude (quite wrongly) that $n^{11} - n^n$ goes to $+\infty$ ...

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+n+to+infinity+%28n%21%29%5E%28n%5E%28e%5E2%29%29%2F%282%5E%28n%21%29%29) says that the limit is zero

Comment: @DatBoi Troposhphere already provided a solution. The sequence can be bounded by $n^{n^{10}}/2^{n!}$ and, as (s)he hinted, the $\ln$ of the last sequence can be easily shown to converge to $-\infty$

Comment: @Momo Yes. My point was to back up this answer with the answer by computer. Moreover the graph proved to be deceptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if
$$A_n=\frac{n!^{(n^{e^2})}}{2^{n!}}$$
Then, using the fact that $n!\le n^n\le 2^{n^2}$ we get for $n>10$:
$$\eqalign{ \ln(A_n)&=n^{e^2}\ln(n!)-(\ln2) n!\le
(\ln2)(n^{e^2+2}-n!)\cr
&\le 
(\ln2)(n^{10}-n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-10))}$$
Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(A_n)=-\infty$ and consequently,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=0$$

Comment: This expression $(\operatorname{ln}2)(n^{10}-n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot(n-10))$ seems to be missing dots